# WPF XamNumericEditor binded to Slider

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, infragistics

I have a XamNumeric editor and a Slider to ease the percentage input.

The problem is that as soon as the user changes the value with the slider, the spin buttons in the editor **get disabled**.

I have the following xaml:

```html
<InfragisticsWpf:XamNumericEditor x:Name="PercentEditor"
    Value="{Binding Percent, Mode=TwoWay}"                        
    ValueType="{x:Type System:Decimal}"
    Mask="nnn %"
    SpinButtonDisplayMode="Always">
    <InfragisticsWpf:XamNumericEditor.ValueConstraint>
        <InfragisticsWpf:ValueConstraint MinInclusive="0" MaxInclusive="100"/>
    </InfragisticsWpf:XamNumericEditor.ValueConstraint>
</InfragisticsWpf:XamNumericEditor>
<Slider 
    Value="{Binding ElementName=PercentEditor, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource DoubleToDecimalConverter}}" 
    Minimum="0" 
    Maximum="100"                        
    IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" 
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    TickFrequency="5">                      
</Slider>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ater some more debugging I have found a solution. The problem with the XamNumericEditor is that on the binding from the other controls it sets the carret poistion on the end of the visible value (% in my case) that's why the spin buttons do not work. To correct the problem I added the following handler:

```html
void NumericEditorOnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 var numericEditor = sender as XamNumericEditor;

 if (numericEditor != null)
 {
  var text = numericEditor.Text;
  var numberMatch = Regex.Match(text, @"\d");
  if (numberMatch.Success)
  {
                    numericEditor.SelectionStart = numberMatch.Index;
  }
 }
}
```

I know this is not the best idea as I had add the handler in the code behind. I would prefer to have a solution directly in the Xaml file, but this solves the issue.

Comment: This is a bug in the infragistics framework, that was fixed in the later versions the solution above it is a workaround, that does not work all in all the cases.

Comment: For adding code with js snippet with "Run code snippet". +1